# web dev environment : cvs + localhost + server in sync : nusphere phped + wamp

Tags: cvs, wamp, phped

I am a freelance web developer (php/js/xhtml/css etc).

Currently:
1) I use wamp on windows 7 for local development (localhost)
2) I use nusphere phped.
3) then when I have to check it on server, I transfer all files through cuteftp to my server.
4) I dont use any kind of CVS at all.

What I want is a development environment where I code in nusphere phped (where I will work on the files in my localhost directory (wamp/www)).
And whenever I save/create/delete any file on my project nusphere automatically:

1) makes that change in localhost (obviously it does that)

2) makes that change in my local cvs (for backup etc)

3) makes that change in my server (server may be different on per project basis) (inbuilt ftp client may be)

Can anyone help me with that? This is the best environment I can think of for web dev. Please give me some advice if you have any better ideas (I just want to code in nusphere / windows 7)

Note:

1) I dont travel a lot, so dont need to access my dev environment from many machines.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, phpEd supports changes to CVS Systems:

> Project management features allow you
>   to manage code and project components.
>   Seamlessly integrated CVS client
>   enables you to easily review changes
>   in old versions of a source files to
>   track bugs while working on the same
>   project in a team of developers. All
>   the common CVS functionality is fully
>   enabled. Windows Shell Integration
>   allows you to work with various
>   Version Control Systems, such as
>   TortoiseSVN, and other tools that
>   integrate to Windows Explorer.

[image]

And I'me almost sure it should have a sync system for AUTO Ftp upload on save

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check support for both feature on phped. Since I have never used cvs before, brances/tags confuse me. better I read some tutorial about it.